# ‘make_shared’ is not a member of ‘boost’

Tags: pcl, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Having a problem with upgrading to Electric. Getting a compile error on code that was fine under Diamondback: " 'make_shared' is not a member of 'boost' "

```
  /home/prp/ros/whatever/src/pointCloudUtils.cpp:118: error: ‘make_shared’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /home/prp/ros/whatever/src/pointCloudUtils.cpp:118: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

The code is as follows:

```
unsigned int minZPt_faster(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> &cloud, const unsigned int kernelSize)
{
  KdTreeFLANN<PointXYZ>nN;

  nN.setEpsilon(.010);
  DefaultPointRepresentation<PointXYZ> pr;
  nN.setPointRepresentation(boost::make_shared<DefaultPointRepresentation<PointXYZ> > (pr));
  nN.setInputCloud(cloud.makeShared());
  nN.setMinPts(3);
  ...
}
```

The version of boost I have is 1.40. Unfortunately, as I didn't write this particular piece of code, I'm not clear on what the problem here is, and would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11274/%E2%80%98make_shared%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98boost%E2%80%99/) by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-09-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) on 2011-09-21**:
That did the trick - thanks!